# Convert coordinates in ARImageTrackingConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

With ARKit 2 a new configuration was added: `ARImageTrackingConfiguration` which according to the [SDK](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arimagetrackingconfiguration) can have better performance and some new use cases.

Experimenting with it on Xcode 10b2 (see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/103894 how to fix the asset loading) my code now correctly calls the delegate that an image was tracked and hereafter a node was added but I could not find any documentation where the coordinate system is located, hence does anybody know how to put the node into the scene for it to overlay the detected image:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {
            let imageNode = SCNNode.createImage(size: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize)
            imageNode.transform = // ... ???
            node.addChildNode(imageNode)
        }
    }
}
```

ps: in contrast to `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` the origin seems to constantly move around (most likely putting the camera into 0,0,0).

pps: `SCNNode.createImage` is a helper function without any coordinate calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that I have read your question correctly, you can do something like the following:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

    let nodeToReturn = SCNNode()

    //1. Check We Have Detected Our Image
    if let validImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {

        //2. Log The Information About The Anchor & Our Reference Image
        print("""
            ARImageAnchor Transform = \(validImageAnchor.transform)
            Name Of Detected Image = \(validImageAnchor.referenceImage.name)
            Width Of Detected Image = \(validImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width)
            Height Of Detected Image = \(validImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
         """)

        //3. Create An SCNPlane To Cover The Detected Image
        let planeNode = SCNNode()

        let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: validImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width,
                                    height: validImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)

        planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white

        planeNode.geometry = planeGeometry

        //a. Set The Opacity To Less Than 1 So We Can See The RealWorld Image
        planeNode.opacity = 0.5

        //b. Rotate The PlaneNode So It Matches The Rotation Of The Anchor
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

        //4. Add It To The Node
        nodeToReturn.addChildNode(planeNode)

        //5. Add Something Such As An SCNScene To The Plane
        if let modelScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/model.scn"), let modelNode = modelScene.rootNode.childNodes.first{

            //a. Set The Model At The Center Of The Plane & Move It Forward A Tad
            modelNode.position = SCNVector3Zero
            modeNode.position.z = 0.15

            //b. Add It To The PlaneNode
            planeNode.addChildNode(modelNode)
        }
    }

    return nodeToReturn

}
```

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction...

Comment: Surprise: that worked nicely, thanks @josh-robbins.

Surprise to me because I thought that the coordinate systems are more complicated in a `ARImageTrackingConfiguration` and the code you've posted is more or less the code I already had running for an `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` - thanks again for clearing out my confusion!